Не мог объяснить причину. Или причины?
Не мог объяснить — причины или причину?
Скажите, пожалуйста, в какой падеж правильно поставить слово "причина"?

В зависимости от того, сколько причин. Если одна - "причину", если много - "причины".

И так и так можно, и дело не во множественно числе слова "причина". Если конкретная вещественная причина - то причину(в.п), а если непонятная, любая - то причины(р.п. или второй винительный). Это что-то вроде партикулярности: купил кило сахара, купил кило сахару; налить воды, налить воду.

Правильно: не мог объяснить причину.
Частица НЕ непосредственно относится к вспомогательному модальному глаголу, что ослабляет отрицание. Также речь идет о конкретном случае, что характерно для В.п. (обратим внимание на совершенный вид основного глагола).
ПРАВИЛО
Это тема у Розенталя:  XLV. УПРАВЛЕНИЕ. §201. Падеж дополнения при переходных глаголах с отрицанием
При переходных глаголах с отрицанием в одних случаях явно 
преобладает употребление родительного падежа дополнения, в 
других – употребление винительного падежа, в третьих – 
наблюдается факультативное их использование.


Винительный падеж, ослабляющий значение отрицания, обычно употребляется в следующих случаях:

12)  обычно в конструкции «не + вспомогательный глагол + инфинитив переходного глагола + дополнение» (т.е. при отнесении дополнения не непосредственно к глаголу с отрицанием, а к инфинитиву, зависящему от глагола с отрицанием, что ослабляет влияние отрицания): не мог представить рукопись, не надеялся выполнить задание. Например: Старик Лаврецкий долго не мог простить сыну его свадьбу (Тургенев); ...Он не мог сдержать улыбку (он же); ...Он не решался сообщить матери и Оле правду о своем несчастье (Б. Полевой).
Реже в этих случаях встречается конструкция с родительным падежом, например: ...Не могла слышать его грустного голоса, не могла видеть его тоски и страданий (Короленко); Мы не умеем брать просто от жизни ее радостей (Куприн);
Примечание (к правилу Розенталя). Вероятно, Р.п. в данных примерах связан с несовершенным видом инфинитива: не могла вообще, а не в конкретном  случае.
